# Add Shapefile code - Why all shapefile features added on the same location on map?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am developing the JS app using 3.15. I have tried this code in my app [Add shapefile](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html) from the esri samples.

but shapefile features added at the same location on map.If the polygon features it displays square but not the actual shape of the polygon.

My map intialextent and Spatialreference for basemap are

```
var initialExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({
    "xmin": 51.53195000000005,
    "ymin": 22.62777042700003,
    "xmax": 56.01812603400003,
    "ymax": 25.164240001000053,
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 4326
    }
});


map = new Map("map", {
    extent: esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(initialExtent),
    zoom: 2,
    logo: false
});

map.addLayer(_baseMap);
```

The code to add the shapefile is following. please help me to get it done asap.

```
// Add Shapefile Start
var portalUrl = "http://www.arcgis.com";

//var form = dom.byId("uploadFormShapefile");
//    on(form, "form:click", function (event) {
on(dom.byId("uploadFormShapefile"), "change", function (event) {
    debugger;
    var fileName = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    if (sniff("ie")) { //filename is full path in IE so extract the file name
        var arr = fileName.split("\\");
        fileName = arr[arr.length - 1];
    }
    if (fileName.indexOf(".zip") !== -1) {//is file a zip - if not notify user
        generateFeatureCollectionShapeFile(fileName);
    }
    else {
        dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML = '<p style="color:red">Add shapefile as .zip file</p>';
    }
});

function generateFeatureCollectionShapeFile(fileName) {
    debugger;
    var name = fileName.split(".");
    //Chrome and IE add c:\fakepath to the value - we need to remove it
    //See this link for more info: http://davidwalsh.name/fakepath
    name = name[0].replace("c:\\fakepath\\", "");

    dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML = '<b>Loading </b>' + name;

    //Define the input params for generate see the rest doc for details
    //http://www.arcgis.com/apidocs/rest/index.html?generate.html
    var params = {
        'name': name,
        'targetSR': map.spatialReference,
        'maxRecordCount': 1000,
        'enforceInputFileSizeLimit': true,
        'enforceOutputJsonSizeLimit': true
    };

    //generalize features for display Here we generalize at 1:40,000 which is approx 10 meters
    //This should work well when using web mercator.

    var extent = esri.geometry.getExtentForScale(map, 40000);
    //var extent = scaleUtils.getExtentForScale(map, 40000); //new esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(scaleUtils.getExtentForScale(map, 40000)); 
    var resolution = extent.getWidth() / map.width;
    params.generalize = true;
    params.maxAllowableOffset = resolution;
    params.reducePrecision = true;
    params.numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal = 0;

    var myContent = {
        'filetype': 'shapefile',
        'publishParameters': JSON.stringify(params),
        'f': 'json',
        'callback.html': 'textarea'
    };

    //use the rest generate operation to generate a feature collection from the zipped shapefile
    request({
        url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
        content: myContent,
        form: dom.byId('uploadFormShapefile'),
        handleAs: 'json',
        load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
            if (response.error) {
                errorHandler(response.error);
                return;
            }
            var layerName = response.featureCollection.layers[0].layerDefinition.name;
            dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML = '<b>Loaded: </b>' + layerName;
            addShapefileToMap(response.featureCollection);
        }),
        error: lang.hitch(this, errorHandler)
    });
}
function errorHandler(error) {
    debugger;
    dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML =
        "<p style='color:red'>" + error.message + "</p>";
}
function addShapefileToMap(featureCollection) {
    debugger;
    //add the shapefile to the map and zoom to the feature collection extent
    //If you want to persist the feature collection when you reload browser you could store the collection in
    //local storage by serializing the layer using featureLayer.toJson()  see the 'Feature Collection in Local Storage' sample
    //for an example of how to work with local storage.
    var fullExtent;
    var layers = [];

    arrayUtils.forEach(featureCollection.layers, function (layer) {
        var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Details", "${*}");
        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(layer, {
            infoTemplate: infoTemplate
        });
        //associate the feature with the popup on click to enable highlight and zoom to
        featureLayer.on('click', function (event) {
            map.infoWindow.setFeatures([event.graphic]);
        });
        //change default symbol if desired. Comment this out and the layer will draw with the default symbology
        changeRenderer(featureLayer);
        fullExtent = fullExtent ?
            fullExtent.union(featureLayer.fullExtent) : featureLayer.fullExtent;
        layers.push(featureLayer);
    });

    map.addLayers(layers);
    map.setExtent(fullExtent.expand(1.25), true);

    dom.byId('upload-status').innerHTML = "";
}
function changeRenderer(layer) {
    //change the default symbol for the feature collection for polygons and points
    var symbol = null;
    switch (layer.geometryType) {
        case 'esriGeometryPoint':
            symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
                'angle': 0,
                'xoffset': 0,
                'yoffset': 0,
                'type': 'esriPMS',
                'url': 'images/BluePin1LargeB.png',
                'contentType': 'image/png',
                'width': 20,
                'height': 20
            });
            break;
        case 'esriGeometryPolygon':
            symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
              new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                new Color([112, 112, 112]), 1), new Color([136, 136, 136, 0.25]));
            break;
    }
    if (symbol) {
        layer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of code going on here - is there anyway you can simplify your example case down into the core location where the problem is happening? Maybe post a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) that has all your code running and showing the problem? http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask